# WooCommerce product: Get a value from a serialized array for WP All Import

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, serialization, woocommerce

I am trying to import WooCommerce product to custom field via WP All Import through custom PHP function.

[image: Custom field settings]

Values are Id's of two products, first product with id = '21147' is show up on the frontend, but the second with id = '54447' is not show up, that's why i want to add it through function.

[image]

I am trying to to import the second value '54447' in custom field with name '_accessory_ids'. The field options is Serialized. I want to add values into an already serialized array.

How can I achieve that with function?

Comment: Even with your edit, it isn’t much clearer. Are you trying to set _static_ values here, the same for each record? Or is this supposed to come from your import file? If the latter, then explain in what format you are getting the data from there. Do you want to import both values into the same field, as a serialized array? You only want to _overwrite_ the field content completely with each new import, or do you want to _add_ values into an already serialized array?

Comment: Still not clear … Don’t see what a screenshot from the frontend is supposed to help clear up here either. I asked you a couple of questions, trying to clarify what you actually want here, so please try and answer those.

Comment: _“I want to add values into an already serialized array.”_ - then you need to _read_ the value of that field for the post in question first. Unless you had a way to somehow get the post id, I don’t see how that would work with a custom inline function - so you will probably have to use one of the hooks WP All Import provides, something like https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/action-reference/#pmxi_update_post_meta

Answer (score 0):

Solution is easy, just need to import post Id's, not a product Id's, i lost two weeks for that problem.